# Is it possible to get bash access in NOT running container?

Tags: bash, docker, containers

I able to run Flask API container successfully. But during the app execution it fails and stops the container for some reason.

I do checked container logs and noticed some file missing error is coming. Now I want to debug what file is missing by accessing `/bin/bash` of stopped container. But it throws an error saying container is not running.

> docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash

Is there any workaround to access `bash` in the STOPPED container?

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use the `docker commit` command.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description):

> It can be useful to commit a container’s file changes or settings into
> a new image. This allows you to debug a container by running an
> interactive shell, or to export a working dataset to another server.

[Resource with a example:](https://thorsten-hans.com/how-to-run-commands-in-stopped-docker-containers)

> We can transform a container into a Docker image using the commit
> command. All we need to know is the name or the identifier of the
> stopped container. (You can get a list of all stopped containers with
> docker ps -a).

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS                    NAMES
0dfd54557799   ubuntu  "/bin/bash" 25 seconds ago  Exited (1) 4 seconds ago  peaceful_feynman
```

> Having the identifier `0dfd54557799` of the stopped container, we can
> create a new Docker image. The resulting image will have the same
> state as the previously stopped container. At this point, we use
> docker run and overwrite the original entrypoint to get a way into the
> container.

```
# Commit the stopped image
docker commit 0dfd54557799 debug/ubuntu

# now we have a new image
docker images list
REPOSITORY    TAG     IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE  
debug/ubuntu  <none>  cc9db32dcc2d   2 seconds ago   64.3MB


# create a new container from the "broken" image
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh debug/ubuntu
# inside of the container we can inspect - for example, the file system
$ ls /app
App.dll
App.pdb
App.deps.json
# CTRL+D to exit the container

# delete the container and the image
docker image rm debug/ubuntu
```

Comment: `docker commit` seems to be interesting. I will try this workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, let me know how it geos as I haven't personally used it myself before.

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  You should use it sparingly, if at all.  It shouldn't be necessary for this case.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about `commit`. I don't see why DavidMaze says it's a bad practice. All other suggestions advised inspecting logs, or starting a new container from original image with a changed entrypoint/etc, that's something completely different than inspecting a dead one. If you restart and change entrypoint/etc, you can CHANGE what happens at startup and may see a different thing. If you need to resurrect a dead container and interactively see what's inside, than commit+runshell is exactly what you need. Saying it's bad is like saying 'git switch -c foobar' is bad.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot.

However, it might be useful to either check the logs or specify bash as an entry point when doing a docker run

Checking logs: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

```
docker logs  <CONTAINER_NAME>
```

Shell Entry point: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime

```
docker run --name <CONTAINER_NAME> --entrypoint /bin/bash <IMAGE_NAME>
```

If you container does not have /bin/bash, try

```
docker run --name <CONTAINER_NAME> --entrypoint /bin/sh <IMAGE_NAME>
```

Comment: In order to run `docker run` command again, I had to delete existing container first.

Comment: yes, otherwise there will be some name and port conflicts

Answer (score 0):

You can't because this container is dead as well as turned down virtual machine is dead. You can check logs using `docker logs` command.

```
docker container ls -aq

docker logs <name_of_your_dead_container>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the man pages from docker-run:

```
      --entrypoint=""
      Overwrite the default ENTRYPOINT of the image
```

So use something like:

```
 docker run --entrypoint=/usr/bin/sleep 1000 ......
```

This will start the container and wait 1000 seconds, allowing you to connect and debug.